# Perform Group By and Sum by property in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-filters

Ok so have a simple page that displays a collection of objects in using `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data| groupBy: 'Id'"`I would like to group the data by a known property and also perform aggregate sum on one of the fields.
I've used the `angular-filter.js` library leveraging the groupBy filter to facilitate this.
The issue now is that I would like to also perform the aggregate sum and also display only a single row for each group. so say I have an array of objects,

```
`[{Id:1,name:"harry",volume:500},
{Id:1,name:"harry",volume:200},
{Id:2,name:"Fred",volume:150},
{Id:2,name:"Fred",volume:500},
{Id:3,name:"Sally",volume:450},
{Id:3,name:"Sally",volume:100}
]`
```

As shown above, the volumes are different for unique id's.
I'd like to return this below after grouping by id and aggregating volumes(sum).

```
`[{Id:1,name:"harry",volume:700},
{Id:1,name:"Fred",volume:650},
{Id:1,name:"Sally",volume:550}
]`
```

**EDIT**
I'd like to toggle between 2 displays i.e (all rows) and  (grouped rows) as the case may be. I've implemented this by using `ng-show` with a checkbox flag to determine which view to display.I'd like to do this without having to write extra mark up as i've done here [MyPlunkr SAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ck9ZSQQbGqjExoRx7fMk?p=preview)
This way is my preferred way but there is a requirement to do this without writing to much extra mark up. Perhaps a custom filter would suffice ?

Comment: Very simple to create object where your ID will be used as keys and then iterate array to populate/update data for each id key

Comment: You could consider using a JQuery function which does the grouping, and call it from your Angular controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the grouped objects on each iteration, so finding the sum is very easy:

```
$scope.getVolumeSum = function(items) {
    return items
        .map(function(x) { return x.volume; })
        .reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });
};
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, items) in data | groupBy: 'Id'">
  id: {{ key }}, name: {{ items[0].name }}, volume: {{ getVolumeSum(items) }}
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hqf1zdpm/)**

Comment: This is pretty much the direction I was tending towards.Really clean javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to work around this i.e group the data and aggregate it so that It displays on the same view without having to create a separate one.
I Implemented a custom filter.

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('Ctrl',[function($scope){
$scope.originalist = []// data is an array of objects.
    $scope.groupdata = function(showlist){
            $scope.newlist = showlist ? $filter('myCustomFilter')($scope.originalist): $scope.originalist; 
     }

}])
.filter('myCustomFilter',function(){
     return function(input){
     //Group the input data and aggregate where necessary
      return data
}

});
```

Then in the html document:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showlist" ng-change="groupdata (showlist)" />
```

---

also in the view:

```
  <tr class="ng-cloak" ng-repeat="d in originalist>
  </tr>
```

So I call the filter when the check box value `showlist` is set to `true`.
Perhaps there is a better way but this is what has worked for me.