# Group data by year, subtotal and grand total on value and create a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

As I am new to angularjs and web technologies, I have a difficulty in solving the below one, I have a data in this below format:

```
[{"MyYear":2015,"Type":"A","SoldValue":55},{"MyYear":2014,"Type":"A","SoldValue":58},{"MyYear":2015,"Type":"B","SoldValue":85},.....]
```

but I want to convert this to an html table in the below format.

`Type   2014    2015    2016    ... Total   Percent
 A       58     55      0       ... 58+55    5%
 B       0      85      0       ... 85       3%
 C       0      0       0       ....

.
.
.
                      GrandTotal    55+85+58 100%`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS you can use the following:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in yourentity | groupBy: 'yourfield'"
```

You can also achieve this in the controller if you want to do more complex stuff, e.g. see: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-grouping-nested-ngrepeat-lists-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: **Andrew Kelly**, and how do I performn subtotal and grand total on particular column

Comment: Create a function which will sum the items e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123711/perform-group-by-and-sum-by-property-in-angularjs

Comment: **Andrew Kelly**, That's mouth full info you have provided,thanks for that, but how about transposing some columns to row as I mentioned above?